# Dependent instances of same class

Tags: python, class

So I have an idea in mind for a project, but i would need to have 2 instances of a certain class output into eachother. I want to make it so that the instance something gets its input from is an attribute of the instance, for example:

```
class Class(object):
    def __init__(self, input):
        self.input = input

a = Class(b)
b = Class(a)
```

Where "Class"is the class that these instances are from.

I hope my question makes my point clear, thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: No, it is not clear. You just have a standard class definition and two instances here.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: he means he wants the two objects to refer to each other at construction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you could design the class constructor in such a way that by default an instance creates its own self-referential input instance:

```
class Class(object):
    def __init__(self, input=None):
        if input None:
            self.input = Class(self)
        else:
            self.input = input

>>> a = Class()
>>> b = a.input
>>> b.input is a
True
```

Or, make it more explicit and just set the input on the first instance after creating the second:

```
class Class(object):
    def __init__(self, input=None):
        self.input = input

>>> a = Class()
>>> b = a.input = Class(a)
>>> a.input is b
True
>>> b.input is a
True
```

Comment: But isn't a its own input now? I need it so that b is a's input and a is b's input

Comment: No, `a` and `b` are each other's input now

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you won't be able to pass object b to the constructor of object a before the object b is created. Of course you may try:

```
a = Class(Class(b(a))
```

to pass just created b to the constructor of a but this time you's want to pass not-yet-created object a to the constructor of a. This won't work either.

But that's only one battle is lost. To win the war you may try:

```
a = Class()
b = Class()
a.input = b
b.input = a
```

Now they can talk to each other.

If you still want to save two lines of code, you may pass a to the constructor of b which will attach newly created b (that means self) to a and vice versa. Constructor of a will be given empy object so it won't do any connection util b gets a to do so.

But to make the code clear I'd prefer the first solution.